# How to correctly convert a MVC controller to an API controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The following controller is developed by ASP.NET Core MVC. I plan to convert it into an API controller. What is the best way to convert MVC-specific features (such as `ModelState`, `Redirect`, `RedirectToAction`, `ViewData`) to API ones?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserDto loginUserDto, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(loginUserDto);

    var rs = await _accountService.SignInAsync(loginUserDto);
    if (rs.Succeeded)
    {
        TempData["notification"] = "<script>swal(`" + "Welcome Back!" + "`, `" + "Hello " + loginUserDto.UserName + ", Welcome back!" + "`,`" + "success" + "`)" + "</script>";
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else if (rs.Data.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        var sendCode = true;
        return RedirectToAction("LoginTwoStep", new { loginUserDto.UserName, loginUserDto.RememberMe, returnUrl, sendCode });
    }
    else if (rs.Data.IsLockedOut)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Account locked");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
    }

    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View(loginUserDto);
}
```

Comment: if I understand the question, the only difference would be you'd return JsonResult...  so "Task<IActionResult>" becomes "Task<JsonResult>".  Redirects would be handled on the front-end.  (you can just return a bool in those cases...)  Back-end errors will come through as XHR header.  For your "account locked, invalid, etc..." custom error strings,  just return those in the returned Json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment said, You need to return `JsonResult` instead of `view` in Web Api, So here if `Modelstate.IsValid` is false, You can use `Return BadRequest(some message)` to return a 400 error. Your frontend framework will achieve redirect between views, If you want to return the redirect Url and some data from backend, you can custom return type

```
public class CustomResponse
    {
        public string redirectUrl { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }        
    }
```

Actione

```
var response = new CustomResponse
{
    redirectUrl = "xxxxxxxxx",
    data = "somed ata"
};
return Ok(response);
```

You can also refer to [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0),[Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#additional-resources).